# How to use the textbox1_keydown?

Tags: vb.net

How do I use key_down event in my vb.net? I have seen so many codes on google but none of them working I don't understand where its going wrong

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx#Y600
2. http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/114278
3. http://forums.devshed.com/net-development-87/keypress-allow-only-letters-and-numbers-with-max-lenght-of-528176.html
4. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/Vsexpressvb/thread/aab1d64c-a9dc-4dd2-8d2f-83a414e9c909
5. http://www.bigresource.com/VB-Lock-textbox-so-the-user-only-can-enter-numbers-a8mxDB7ouq.html
6. http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-96951.html

Above are the links I googled and they are many links =I have googled to work on key_down events on vb.net But my god its aint working I dont know what to do.

1) How do I use textbox1_keydown event are there any necessary steps taken before using it ( why its aint workin?)

2) can anyone post a sample of these "a textbox that allows only numbers from user using key_down"

3) I see people using e.keychar but in my vb.net(2008) I dont have that keyword I guess e.keycode must be used is that right? or e.keyvalue?

4) I see e.keycode = keys.A but I need to accept 'a' not "A" How do I specify a number or letter with their ascii value ?

Comment: If you could post what you have tried, we should be able to help you better.

Comment: @markhall. I have tried what i found on google,and what you tried ? and for these I have shown you the links i read and i tried it in the way they gave the code but it was not working and why a -1 to the question? written the code for keypress event but not working that was my problem so i wanted to know, Is there any changes i have to do for textbox properties before i use

Comment: @all Perfect juss perfect thats why i like the stackoverflow no matter where i try when i dont get the solution stackoverflow helps me Im so thankful to these site and the guys behind these and ofcourse for the answeers posted and questions :) finally its working guys full of thanks...

Comment: @markhall sorry if Im not clear in my question anyways thanks! But i started working on visual basic from a week, I dont know how to handle the things clearly learning from msdn .net tutorials

Comment: It was not a matter of being clear, it was seeing what you had tried so that we could see where you were going wrong. As far as the -1 I don't know why since it wasn't me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not able to use KeyPress for some reason?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.Handled = True    'Prevents all numbers from from being placed
    End If

    If Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) = 97 Then
        e.Handled = True    'Prevents "a" from being placed
    End If
End Sub
```

This should do what you need. You can find a list of ASCII codes [here](http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/docs/ASCIICodes.aspx) if you don't have one already. Take a look at the intellisense for Char. and check out all the useful things you can filter on. You can also specify exact ASCII values by converting them to int.

Comment: Its working Both answers working I dont know which one to accept ! but i will give +1 for both answers !

Comment: Go ahead and accept the one from Lars, doesn't matter to me. Just accept one of them :)

Comment: @eclipse I m need of some vb.net books or documents or pdfs or tutorials on internet can u suggest some links which helps me for more understandindg

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting a little confused between KeyDown and KeyPress.

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
  If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If
End Sub
```

If you are trying to enter *only* numbers and the lower case "a" then:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
  If Not (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) = Asc("a") Or Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) Then
    e.Handled = True
  End If
End Sub
```